# How to remove logiops/logid (Logitech Options for Linux)

Tags: uninstall, delete, logitech, software-uninstall

After installing logid/logiops I have decided I no longer want it since my mouse functions perfectly fine and thought it would bring other extra benefits

I followed the installation steps provided in the readme of [this github repo](https://github.com/PixlOne/logiops). I cloned the repo in my home directory and continued with all the steps provided in the readme

How do I delete it?

I have tried to do sudo apt remove logid or logiops but nothing works

Comment: How you remove software depends entirely upon how you originally installed it. Please [edit your question above](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1247959/edit) to clearly explain how you installed the software. Links to any instructions that you followed would also be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you followed the instructions you have installed the `logid` daemon in `/usr/local/bin` and you enabled this with systemctl.

To remove, work backwards, first stop the daemon and disable its automated starting:

```
sudo systemctl disable --now logid
```

This is essentially enough to not further make use of `logid`. If you want you can remove the binary:

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/logid
```

and the sources (check if there is nothing important under logiops first):

```
rm -rf ~/logiops
```

That `apt remove` didn't work is because you did not install this from a `.deb` package.

Comment: "/lib/systemd/system/logid.service" should also be deleted